# Axis 1.4 is not decoding SOAP envelope when HTTP status is 202 - bug or feature?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis, http-status-codes

I'm connecting to web service using Axis 1.4. This service signals error by responding with SOAP envelope with error description and HTTP status code 202. The response looks like that:

```
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
 <TestResponse>
  <TestResult>wrong format</TestResult>
 </TestResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The test response is described in WSDL:

```
  <s:element name="TestResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="s:string"/>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

So, in my opinion everything is OK. The problem is, I don't get that error message with Axis generated stub, receiving `null` instead. As I debugged, I've found the line in `HTTPSender` class line 705:

```
if ((returnCode > 199) && (returnCode < 300)) {
    if (returnCode == 202) {
        return inp;
    }
    // SOAP return is OK - so fall through
}
```

It skips the code, that decodes SOAP envelope. So, finally, I've sent wrong request (it can be anything runtime, such as user password expired), I receive error description, but because I use Axis, I have no access to it and receive only `null`, which makes debugging very hard (the response I posted I've found using Wireshark).

My question is, is it bug or feature? Is the company that have made web service misusing HTTP status 202 or standard allows it and Axis is too primitive to support it? At best I would like to avoid coding communication manually using `HttpClient` from apache or anything similar....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug. The HTTP 202 Accepted status code is used to indicate that a request has been accepted, but further processing is required in order to complete it. The response ***should*** have a `Location` header representing a callback that can be made to the service, to check the request status, and an optional body with a descriptive message.

For a web service, I would expect that service implementors process the body response as long as its content matched the service contract (in this case the WSDL). But the implementors of Axis might have felt differently.

In any case, the vendor is incorrectly using 202 status codes to return errors, and that is a (big) part of the problem.

Comment: So propably both have errors, but the question is, what to do with it? Is modifying Axis sources adequate solution?

Comment: You may have to patch Axis. Looks like they have an outstanding request for this against 1.x branch that hasn't been resolved since 2005 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-1845.